# Write dec number $99$ in another number system.

Tags: number-theory, number-systems

If you know that: 
\begin{eqnarray*}
a^2 = a \\
a + a = b \\
y^2 =y  \\
y + y = y \\
z^2 = bb \\
z + z = aa
\end{eqnarray*}
How can the decimal number $99$ be written in this number system?

** What methods do I need to do in order to find any result? 
   Just give me a direction **

I tried to substitute everything but the result was very weird.

Comment: What do you mean with $y^2=y$ or $y+y=y$? The latter one obviously implieas $y=0$, except you do not mean it in the usual sense (but then I cannot guess the way in which you mean it). What number system are you talking about?

Comment: Is just a number system in some "unknown planet", the actual problem was if you are in another planet and you find a calculator, then using that calculator you observe these things I wrote above, than how would you write our decimal 99 in their "language".

Answer (score 2):

$a^2=a$ so $a=0$ or $a=1$. $a+a=b$ and $b \neq a $ so $a=1$ and $b=2$.

The third & fourth equations give $y=0$.

Now let $B$ be the base, so $2B+2=z^2$ and $2z=B+1$, giving $B=7$.

$99_{10}=\color{red}{201_7}$ which is $\color{blue}{bya}$ in their language.

Comment: But we still don't know whether the answer is `bya` or `ayb`.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I did not realise that we had to translate it back into their language. $\ddot \smile$

Comment: I did not get the Base, how did you implement that within the equations?

Comment: $22_{B} =2B+2$ ($2$ in the $B$ column & $2$ in the unit column). Similarly $11_{B}=B+1$.

Comment: The question was, "How can the decimal number 99 be written in this number system?" And again, as far as I can see there is no evidence that would let us conclude that would be `bya` rather than `ayb`.